# Is it advisable to change kstream message key or message after it is read by consumer for storing internal state

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am doing some heavy processing inside my kstream filter and the same processing would be required by downstream transformer and mapper. As filter is stateless operation, is it a good idea to add some data in the key or value passed in filter and use it in downstream mapper/transformer?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the data for joins, then altering the key can be useful, but you need to be mindful that the data will be re-partitioned into downstream/internal topics

If you simply want metadata on the record, the recommendation would be to use headers, if not modify the value itself.

`filter` DSL cannot modify the data, however. Use `map` or the Processor API to forward a new record